# Get jQuery select options by value using prop( )

Tags: jquery

I am trying to see if an option is already in a select but I want to use a previously declared variable set to the object, without the `option[value]` selector.

Example: will evaluate to true if option exists (I dont want to use this)

`$("#mySelect option[value='myValue']").length > 0;`

If I set `#mySelect` to a variable instead, not using the `option[ ] selector`

`var obj = $("#mySelect");`

How would I check the same thing?

I tried the `prop('options')` but can't seem to check by value...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You first get a handle on the select and option as coded below

```
var mySelect = $("#mySelect");
var optionMyValue = mySelect.find("option[value='myValue']");
```

Once they're stored in variables, you no longer need to requery the DOM.  I made a small code snippet illustrating this.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  // Store mySelect and optionMyValue in a variable
  var mySelect = $("#mySelect");
  var optionMyValue = mySelect.find("option[value='myValue']");

  $("#button").click(function () {
    if (optionMyValue.length) {
      optionMyValue.prop("selected", true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="mySelect">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="myValue">myValue</option>
  <option value="myValue2">myValue2</option>
  <option value="myValue3">myValue3</option>
  <option value="myValue4">myValue4</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="button" value="Click to select myValue">
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I believe you read the question wrong.  I understand how to do it the way you showed.  How about getting it after I have only set the element to a variable, not using the option selector?  I edited my question to be more specific.

Comment: @NorCalKnockOut Unless I'm mistaken I think my answer does what you asked. It assigns a variable to the option once so that it can be reused. If that's not what you're after, then I truly don't understand what question you're asking.

Comment: Don't use `option[value='myValue']"` and do the same thing with `var $mySelect = $("#mySelect")`

Comment: Assume `$myselect` is already set and I don't want to hit the DOM again... does that make sense?

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  Sorry for the bad question explanation, it was hard to put into words.

Comment: @NorCalKnockOut no worries.  Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {


  var optionMyValue = $("#mySelect");

  $("#button").click(function () {
    if (optionMyValue.children("option[value='myValue']").length) {
      optionMyValue.children("option[value='myValue']").prop("selected", true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="mySelect">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="myValue">myValue</option>
  <option value="myValue2">myValue2</option>
  <option value="myValue3">myValue3</option>
  <option value="myValue4">myValue4</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="button" value="Click to select myValue">
```